# Get the name of the program executable (as in paramstr(0)) but get it as a Unicode string in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I want to copy a file from the selflocation to another location like that:

```
var
NewFile        : WideString;
MyOwnLocation  : WideString;
begin
NewFile   := 'C:\mycopy.exe';
// CopyFileW (PWideChar(paramstr(0)), PWideChar(NewFile), false); // ===> doesn't work
MyOwnLocation := paramstr(0);
CopyFileW  (PWideChar(MyOwnLocation), PWideChar(NewFile), false); // ===> works but not sure if Unicode supported...    
end;
```

it works when I copy paramstr(0) to a WideString, but I'm still not sure if paramstr(0) is already UNICODE. Is there maybe a WindowsAPI that returns the current location of my file in a wideString?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you tried simply renaming your exe to something with a non-simple-ASCII character (for example a Russian character) in it and then executing it from a command line window? If necessary by tping the first character of the name and then using tab to make window cycle through the names that start with that character? It is a very simple way to find the answer to your question. And samples of Unicode characters can usually be found very simply by doing a search on Delphi subjects or checking the Embarcadero blogs. Plenty of Russians blogging...

Comment: Are you writing malware?

Comment: true. I should have put a unicode character in a foldername or filename. @WarrenP why do you ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use `GetModuleFileNameW`, the unicode version of the api that `ParamStr(0)` internally use:

```
var
  NewFile: WideString;
  MyOwnLocation: WideString;
  Len: DWORD;
begin
  NewFile := 'C:\mycopy.exe';
  SetLength(MyOwnLocation, 260);
  Len := GetModuleFileNameW(0, PWideChar(MyOwnLocation), Length(MyOwnLocation));
  Win32Check(Bool(Len));
  if GetLastError <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then begin
    SetLength(MyOwnLocation, Len);
    CopyFileW (PWideChar(MyOwnLocation), PWideChar(NewFile), false);
  end else
    // handle fail due to insufficient buffer
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `CopyFileW` with `ParamStr(0)` directly doesn't work because `ParamStr(0)` returns `AnsiString` in Delphi 7 (the default type for `string`), and so it doesn't match the first parameter type expected (`PWideChar`).

The only way to do it is the way you are - assign the content of `ParamStr(0)` to a `WideString` variable first, and then use that as a parameter to `CopyFileW`.

Windows does most conversions between Unicode and ANSI transparently without any effort on your part when using a non-Unicode API (`CopyFileA`, which Delphi 7's `Windows` unit maps `CopyFile` to, so you should just use it instead.