# delphi 7, FastMM4 cannot install work around

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastmm

i am working on an application that uses `FastMM4`, from [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/files/).
So i have added the `FastMM4.pas` to the uses clause right at the beginning. In the application i need to run a `batch` file after `FinalizeMemoryManager;` in the `finalization` of `unit FastMM4;` like this

```
  initialization
        RunInitializationCode;

  finalization
        {$ifndef PatchBCBTerminate}
        FinalizeMemoryManager;
        RunTheBatFileAtTheEnd; //my code here..calling a procedure
       {$endif}

 end.
```

then my code for **RunTheBatFileAtTheEnd** is :

```
 procedure RunTheBatFileAtTheEnd;
 begin
 //some code here....
  sFilePaTh:=SysUtils.ExtractFilePath(applicaTname)+sFileNameNoextension+'_log.nam';
 ShellExecute(applcatiOnHAndle,'open', pchar(sExeName),pchar(sFilePaTh), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
 end;
```

For this i need to use `SysUtils,shellapi` in the uses clause of fastmm4 unit. **But** using them 
this message comes 
[image]

But if i remove `SysUtils,shellapi` from the uses it works.
I still need all the features of fastmm4 installed but with `SysUtils,shellapi`, fastmm4 is not installed

I have a unit of my own but its finalization is executed before fastmm4 finalization.

can anyone tell me can how to fix this problem?

**EDIT- 1**

```
unit FastMM4;
//...
...
implementation

 uses
   {$ifndef Linux}Windows,{$ifdef FullDebugMode}{$ifdef Delphi4or5}ShlObj,{$else}
  SHFolder,{$endif}{$endif}{$else}Libc,{$endif}FastMM4Messages,SysUtils,shellapi;
```

my application

```
 program memCheckTest;
   uses
      FastMM4,
```

**EDIT-2 :**

(after @SertacAkyuz answer),i removed `SysUtils` and it worked , but i still need to run the batch file to open an external application through `RunTheBatFileAtTheEnd`. The Reason is ..i want a external application to run only after FastMM4 as been out of the `finalization`. The `sExeName` is the application that will run the file `sFilePaTh`(.nam) . can any one tell how to do this? without `uninstalling FastMM4`.

Comment: Which uses clause? If in the interface, you make FastMM4 dependent on them and they will be initialized first including any units that they depend on. Any memory allocation done there would cause this. Have you tried moving the two units to the implementation clause? That should shift the dependency order.

Comment: @MarjanVenema : i have added new code for the uses clause, `SysUtils,shellapi;` are in the `implementation`

Comment: You have to do without 'sysutils'. The code in initialization section of 'sysutils' needs allocating memory, hence the memory manager has to be set.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ok, so `sysutils` is the problem, i will try something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FastMM checks to see if the default memory manager is set before installing its own by a call to `IsMemoryManagerSet` function in 'system.pas'. If the default memory manager is set, it declines setting its own memory manager and displays the message shown in the question.

The instruction in that message about *'fastmm4.pas' should be the first unit in the project's .dpr file* has the assumption that 'fastmm4.pas' itself is not modified.

When you modify the uses clause of 'fastmm4.pas', if any of the units that's included in the uses clause has an `initialization` section, than that section of code have to run before the initialization section of 'fastmm4.pas'. If that code requires allocating/feeing memory via RTL, then the default memory manager is set.

Hence you have to take care changing 'fastmm4.pas' to not to include any such unit in the uses clause, like 'sysutils.pas'.

---

Below sample code (no error checking, file checking etc..) shows how can you launch FastMM's log file with Notepad (provided the log file exists) without allocating any memory:

```
var
  CmdLine: array [0..300] of Char; // increase as needed
  Len: Integer;
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;

initialization
  ...  // fastmm code

finalization
{$ifndef PatchBCBTerminate}
  FinalizeMemoryManager;       // belongs to fastmm

  // Our application is named 'Notepad' and the path is defined in AppPaths
  CmdLine := 'Notepad "';  // 9 Chars (note the opening quote)
  Len := windows.GetModuleFileName(0, PChar(@CmdLine[9]), 260) + 8;

  // assumes the executable has an extension.
  while CmdLine[Len] <> '.' do
    Dec(Len);

  CmdLine[Len] := #0;
  lstrcat(CmdLine, '_MemoryManager_EventLog.txt"'#0); // note the closing quote

  ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
  SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
  CreateProcess(nil, CmdLine, nil, nil, False,
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, sInfo, pInfo);

{$endif}

end.
```

Comment: i need to have the `sFilePaTh:=SysUtils.ExtractFilePath(applicaTname)` which i cannot get without the `SysUtils` so is there any way to get the application file path? (even `application.exe').

Comment: ok..Question: `Notepad "` my application name is `tracker.exe` how do i write it in place of `Notepad "`?

Comment: @Presley - Better use full path. Count characters, like in the answer. `CmdLine:='C:\somefolder\tracker.exe "`, that used 27 characters, then `Len:=GetModuleFileName(0,PChar(@CmdLine[27]),..)`. Increase size of CmdLine to account room for increased usage: `var CmdLine:array[0..350] of Char` etc.. Use the debugger to follow how CmdLine is building up..

Comment: i just tried the it works with hardcoded path but how do i get the path of my application (installation path) as i cant use registry..how???

Comment: @Presley - One option is to register your application in the 'App Paths' key or the environment path ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) so that you don't have to find it. Another one can be to try to directly use the api [registry functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I think it's not possible to workout further details in comments.

Comment: ok, nice idea..i m just posting a new question as this discussion is different from the actual question..please post your answer when i post the question

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sertac's answer, but also would like to give a recommendation, if you insist on using `SysUtils.pas`. The answer is don't use it, and extract what you need out of it and put it in your own copy. Here's what you would need below - `ExtractFilePath` used `LastDeliminator`, which used `StrScan`, and also 2 constants, so I copied them into this new unit and named it `MySysUtils.pas`.

This is also widely used for people who don't want to have a bunch of extra code compiled which they will never use (You would have to be absolutely sure it's not used anywhere in any units though).

```
unit MySysUtils;

interface

const
  PathDelim = '\';
  DriveDelim = ':';

implementation

function StrScan(const Str: PWideChar; Chr: WideChar): PWideChar;
begin
  Result := Str;
  while Result^ <> #0 do begin
    if Result^ = Chr then
      Exit;
    Inc(Result);
  end;
  if Chr <> #0 then
    Result := nil;
end;

function LastDelimiter(const Delimiters, S: string): Integer;
var
  P: PChar;
begin
  Result := Length(S);
  P := PChar(Delimiters);
  while Result > 0 do begin
    if (S[Result] <> #0) and (StrScan(P, S[Result]) <> nil) then
      Exit;
    Dec(Result);
  end;
end;

function ExtractFilePath(const FileName: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := LastDelimiter(PathDelim + DriveDelim, FileName);
  Result := Copy(FileName, 1, I);
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1,hey great trick.!! but what about the `Application.ExeName` uses `forms.pas` and i will still have the same problem of Fastmm4 not installing , so what to do in this case? to get the `Application.ExeName`

Comment: @Presley - You can use 'GetModuleFileName' as that's what VCL use for ParamStr(0). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763243/get-the-name-of-the-program-executable-as-in-paramstr0-but-get-it-as-a-unico/10765429#10765429) for a sample implementation (you can use the ansi version of the function).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ok, but i think u missed the link

Comment: I just don't see the possibility of making such calls, which require usage of memory, before FastMM has initialized. I'm scratching my head trying to understand why you need to put this type of code inside FastMM4.pas.

Comment: @JerryDodge : i am trying to make an application that will open the `log` file that i created by `fastmm4` which happens to be created after in `FinalizeMemoryManager` (in finalization)..i want my application to pop up and show the `log` file now that is only possible i guess after `FinalizeMemoryManager` has finished execution...can you help how to run my app after `FinalizeMemoryManager`?

Comment: @PresleyDias I think you have no choice but to run your code just before FastMM finalizes.

Comment: @Presley - I thought there was enough information on this page to achieve that. Anyway, I modified my answer for a simple example.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz hey i will try and get back to u