# Delphi 7, use FastMM4 for getting application path and open application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, createprocess, fastmm

i am working on a application in `Delphi 7` that will run and display the the log created by `FastMM4.pas`.

The application will be installed anywhere on the system. I have modified the `FastMM4.pas` so that it will `CreateProcess`(inshort execute my application)
The code from my  [previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10784743/1051198) and [Sertac Akyuz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10785566/1051198)

The `leakTracker.exe` will take in the fastmm4's log file as the parameter and open the file and display. The modified `fastMM4.pas` will be used in any other application.

```
Procedure OpenTheLeakReader
 begin
 CmdLine := 'C:\Program Files\leakTracker\leakTracker.exe "';  
 lstrcat(CmdLine,CTheArGuements ); 
 ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
 SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
 CreateProcess(nil, CmdLine, nil, nil, False,  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, sInfo, pInfo);
end;
```

This works fine but i have hardcoded the `path` because to get my application path..

```
                 [FastMM4]  -cannot use SysUtils.pas     //*1
                            -cannot use Registry.pas     //*2
                            -cannot use ParamStr(0)      //*3
                            -cannot use unitWithSysRegis //*4

                 [someAplicationWhichWillUseFastMM4] -Uses FastMM4.pas
```

in the `FAstMM4.pas` `finalization` i have this

```
          if ifLeakedMemory then OpenTheLeakReader;
```

since i cannot have

`*1 - SysUtils.pas` - in FastMM4.pass as this will un-install fastmmm4

`*2 - Registry.pas` - to search `leakTracker` installation path but will uninstall fastmm4

`*3 -  paramstr(0)`  - it gives a error at the close of application.

`*4 - unitWithSysRegis` - with SysUtils,Registry also not possible in Fastm4 uses clause.

So I am stuck as how to get the path of `leakTracker.exe` and send the path of the log file to the `leakTracker.exe' through CreateProcess.

Comment: You could import the Windows [registry functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875.aspx) yourself?

Comment: @Blorgbeard i didnt get how to do that..any examples?

Comment: Actually, can you use `windows` unit? It has `RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegGetValueEx` etc. If not, you could copy the definitions from there.

Comment: @Blorg FastMM cannort use any units other than implicit System.

Comment: FastMM is using 'windows.pas' already.

Comment: @sertac if so then  that is because Windows.pas does not do heap allocation in its initialization

Comment: @SertacAkyuz can you give examples of [your suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784743/delphi-7-fastmm4-cannot-install-work-around/10785566#comment14308545_10785566)?

Comment: @Presley - You have a problem with `lstrcat` usage, you're overrunning 'CmdLine' (the code in the previous question allocates a buffer first).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `OpenTheLeakReader` my leakTracker.exe run but with exact code from previous q doesnt ran..i tried with proper @CmdLine[46] also

Comment: @sertac sounds like you know what this is all about and are better placed to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For an explanation first (regarding the linked question in the question), this question is not just about not being able to use units (having initialization sections requiring memory allocation) in FastMM4.pas. OP thinks that his code has to run after FastMM finalizes the memory manager. FastMM raises an exception if memory is allocated after that, so allocating memory via RTL is prohibited.)

---

Use the api registry functions as pointed out in the previous question or Blorgbeard commented to this question. Incorporated with the previous code, it would become something like this:

```
var
  hReg: HKEY;
  Ret: Longint;
  RegDataType, RegDataSize: DWORD;
  CmdLine: array [0..560] of Char; // increase as needed
  Len: Integer;
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;


initialization
{$ifndef BCB}
  // fastmm code
{$endif}

finalization
{$ifndef PatchBCBTerminate}
  FinalizeMemoryManager;  // fastmm code



  Ret := windows.RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                  'SOFTWARE\[YourProgram]', // registry key to your program's path
                  0, KEY_READ, hReg);

  RegDataType := REG_SZ;
  RegDataSize := 260;
  Ret := windows.RegQueryValueEx(hReg,
                  'path',       // registry value containing your program's path
                  nil, @RegDataType, @CmdLine, @RegDataSize);
  RegCloseKey(hReg);

  CmdLine[RegDataSize - 1] := ' ';
  CmdLine[RegDataSize] := '"';     // open doublequote in case spaces in path
  Len := windows.GetModuleFileName(0,
          PChar(@CmdLine[RegDataSize + 1]), 260) + RegDataSize;

  while CmdLine[Len] <> '.' do     // assumes executable has an extension
    Dec(Len);
  CmdLine[Len] := #0;
  lstrcat(CmdLine, '_MemoryManager_EventLog.txt"'#0);  // closing doublequote

  ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
  SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
  CreateProcess(nil, CmdLine, nil, nil, False,
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, sInfo, pInfo);

{$endif}
end.
```